# Can URL tell jQuery to run a function in Angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have written an angularjs web app and i want to add a link to an email that when clicked will trigger a function in the controller of the angularjs app and afterwards lunch a page on the site based on the result. Can anyone help me with this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Very unclear.. will the email link launch the site?

Comment: Okay, i will clearify...the link will initially hit the function and then at the end of the function open a page on the site.

Comment: Sounds like a good use of angular routing. Let us know how your attempt goes.

Comment: right...thanks mccainz...yes that should work....will keep you posted......

Comment: FYI: Angular's router is fairly basic and many developers opt for https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router.

Comment: year mccainz....i used a similar page to solve it...   https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07

Answer (score -1, accepted):

inside the app.js i created two routes

```
 $routeProvider
  .when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
    controller: 'MainCtrl'
  })
  .when('/main/:couponValue', {
    templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
    controller: 'RecheduleBookingCtrl'
    })
```

and then i created another controller that takes a parameter for the second route

```
var controllerId = 'MainCtrl';
app.controller(controllerId, [
    '$scope', 'customerFactory', '$window', function ($scope, customerFactory, $window) {
        $scope.awesomeThings = [
        'HTML5 Boilerplate',
        'AngularJS',
        'Karma'
        ];
    }
]);

var controllerTwoId = 'RecheduleBookingCtrl';
app.controller(controllerTwoId, [
    '$scope', '$routeParams', function ($scope, $routeParams) {
        $scope.couponValue = $routeParams.couponValue;
        $scope.init = function reschedule() {
            alert('eureka');
        }
        $scope.init(); 
    }
]);
```

and that was all...thanks guys u saved me another 24 hour of research.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a route and do your stuff with resolve. Something like this:

```
$routeProvider
  .when("/link_from_email/:user/:id", {
    resolve: {
      handle: function ($route, $location) {
        var user = $route.current.params.user,
            id   = $route.current.params.id;
        // do stuff
        $location.path("/somewhere_else");
      }
    }
  })
```